# A question regarding a proof pertaining to: for all $n\in\omega$, $(\aleph_{n+1})^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_{n+1}\cdot(\aleph_n)^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

I would like to show:

> > for all $n\in\omega$, $(\aleph_{n+1})^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_{n+1}\cdot(\aleph_n)^{\aleph_0}$

Actually I see this problem can be solved using the approach Brian Scott uses here:

[For every $n < \omega$, $\aleph_n^{\aleph_0} = \max(\aleph_n,\aleph_0^{\aleph_0})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82835/for-every-n-omega-aleph-n-aleph-0-max-aleph-n-aleph-0-aleph-0)

Most unfortunately, Brian hasn't been here for over a year (hope he's OK), so perhaps someone would explain one aspect of his proof:

> > Now consider a function $\varphi:\aleph_0\to\aleph_m$; $\aleph_m$ is an uncountable regular cardinal, so $\sup\{\varphi(k):k\in\aleph_0\}<\aleph_m$, and $\varphi$ actually maps $\aleph_0$ into $\eta$ for some ordinal $\eta<\aleph_m$.

My question is why, since $\aleph_m$ is an uncountable regular cardinal, its cofinality is $\aleph_m$, so why is the $\text{sup}$ less than $\aleph_m$?

Comment: By definition of cofinality

Comment: So the inequality is actually an equality.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I was concerned with an intermediary step. These notes https://caicedoteaching.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/580-cardinalarithmetic.pdf on p. 9 attribute it to Tarski. "Intro to Cardinal Arithmetic" p. 64 attributes it to Hausdorff.

Comment: I suspected that was the case. I said it anyway

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Appreciated; happy to receive all the help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that $\sup \{\varphi(k):k\in\omega\}$ is $\aleph_m$. Then, the sequence of sets $\bigcup_{k\in\omega}\{\varphi(j):j\leq k\}$ is cofinal in $\aleph_m$ and has length $\aleph_0$. This contradicts the regularity of $\aleph_m$ ($m\neq 0$ since $\aleph_m$ is an uncountable cardinal).

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been studying it for a while, and maybe I could ask some follow-up questions. First, the length $\aleph_0$ that you mention comes from $\bigcup_{k\in\omega}$? So is that really the key, that with a domain of $\omega$ you will never reach $\aleph_m$?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea of cofinality: since $\aleph_m$ is regular, it is its own cofinality, so you need a sequence of $\aleph_m$, and no less, sets smaller than it to cover it.